# Special charecter removal from dataframe in pandas while using Deduplication

Tags: python, pandas, python-dedupe

I am using deduplication in my data frame I am getting warning-

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_dedupe
scholar=pd.read_csv('Scholar.csv')
Scholar_final=pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(scholar,['idScholar','ROW_ID'])
```

Warning Message :

```
Importing data ...
 FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
  df[i] = df[i].str.replace('[^\w\s\.\-\(\)\,\:\/\\\\]','')
```

What does it mean?
I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Use `df[i] = df[i].str.replace('[^\w\s.-(),:/\\]','', regex=True)` to explicitly use regex replacement for `str.replace` which is the current default, but will soon not be the default behaviour.

Comment: You didn't include the code for your loop with the "i" variable

Comment: @HenryEcker Isn't that the answer then?